# Is serial output via USB an option to make a rs232 connection to a pi?

Tags: pi-3, usb, serial

There is a lot to find online to make a serial port with the gio 14 and 15 pins on the pi, isnt a usb to serial converter on a usb port of the pi a good option ? I ask this because i want to use the pi as a serial server for attached rs232 devices. What are the possibilities of a pi 3 to set up a serial connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a USB serial dongle is a perfectly good option.

You probably don't see many online tutorials as saying "plug it in" does not make for a very interesting tutorial.